# How to export a mysql database using Command Prompt?

Tags: mysql

I have a database that is quite large so I want to export it using Command Prompt but I don't know how to.

I am using WAMP.

Comment: DOS? are you using Windows 98?  Or do you mean the command prompt?

Comment: Of youre using wamp , you should also have phpmyadmin, with the export option

Answer (score 681, accepted):

First check if your command line recognizes mysql command. If not go to command & type in:

```
set path=c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.36\bin
```

Then use this command to export your database:

```
mysqldump -u YourUser -p YourDatabaseName > wantedsqlfile.sql
```

You will then be **prompted for the database password**.

This exports the database to the path you are currently in, while executing this command

**Note: *[Here are some detailed instructions](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/#more-184)* regarding both import and export**

Comment: I am getting this error mysqldump: Got error: 1556: You can't use locks with log tables. when using LOCK TABLES

Comment: @Ammad, You might be trying to dump the logs tables as well. You need to exclude them. I suggest asking a different question with further details. If you want to me to look into it, give me the link as well. I am happy to look into it.

Comment: I am running it from VSCODE extension and it is showing `Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump -u mypu -p mypu>abc.sql' at line 1`

and I have 5.7.20 version of mysql

Comment: If you dont want to set a variable path in windows globally (like me) just  ``cd C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql(mysql version)\bin\ `` and then run your mysqldump command.

Comment: If you have any Stored Procedures or Functions or events you need to add --routines and --events to export them also, see a blog post about it here: https://programalitics.substack.com/p/mysql-database-export-tips

Answer (score 132):

Simply use the following command,

**For Export:**

```
mysqldump -u [user] -p [db_name] | gzip > [filename_to_compress.sql.gz]
```

**For Import:**

```
gunzip < [compressed_filename.sql.gz]  | mysql -u [user] -p[password] [databasename]
```

*Note:* There is no space between the keyword '-p' and your password.

Comment: I think you missed the fact that he's using WAMP - Windows... gunzip / gzip are not bundled with Windows. It might be possible the run your command after installing some stuff, but I think you've missed that fact.

Comment: Specifying `gzip -9` makes the resulting file a bit smaller, because the maximum compression is used.

Answer (score 57):

Well you can use below command,

`mysqldump --databases --user=root --password your_db_name > export_into_db.sql`

and the generated file will be available in the same directory where you had ran this command.

You could find more on the official reference for `mysqldump`: [Import Export MySQL DB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html)

**Note**: use `--databases` instead of `--database` since the last one is no more supported.

Enjoy :)

Comment: For those who get an error like "Access denied when using LOCK TABLES", you should add the "--single-transaction" parameter to the command.

Comment: I got an error `mysqldump: [ERROR] unknown option '--database'` but wit exclusion of `--database` it has worked.

Comment: @Skyrpex Thanks, that was the solution I've been looking for.

Answer (score 46):

First of all 
open command prompt then open **bin** directory in **cmd** (i hope you're aware with **cmd** commands)
go to **bin** directory of your MySql folder in **WAMP** program files.

run command

```
mysqldump -u db_username -p database_name > path_where_to_save_sql_file
```

press enter system will export particular database and create sql file to the given location.

i hope you got it :)
if you have any question please let me know.

Comment: My friend i've tried to explain process a bit. rather then giving direct command

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump -h 10.0.0.31 -p -u asfuser asfd8crm > var/downloads/db.sql' at line 1
mysql> mysqldump -h 10.0.0.31 -p -u asfuser asfd8crm > var/downloads

Answer (score 26):

Locate your mysql instance with:

```
which mysql
```

If this is correct then export with the following (else navigate to the mysql instance in your mamp folder in bin):

```
mysqldump -u [username] -p [password] [dbname] > filename.sql
```

And if you wish to zip it at the sametime:

```
mysqldump -u [username] -p [password] [db] | gzip > filename.sql.gz
```

You can then move this file between servers with:

```
scp user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/path_to_your_dump/filename.sql.gz your_detination_path/
```

(where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the server IP address)

And then import it with:

```
gunzip filename.sql.gz | mysql -u [user] -p [password] [database]
```

Comment: Again, **W** AMP => Windows. **which** is a Linux command. gunzip / gzip are not bundled with Windows - and may not be available. scp... you get the point.

Comment: *The answer of Opentuned is great*. One small thing is removing the actual `password` from the command line : mysqldump -u [username] -p [dbname] > filename.sql This prevents people searching your history for the password.

Comment: @Opentuned, What's with the linux fetish?

Comment: for -p [pasword] must be near e.g : `mysqldump -u tutorials -p'mypassword' -h 127.0.0.1 database_name > file_backup_database_name_.sql` _Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure._

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump -h 10.0.0.31 -p -u asfuser asfd8crm > var/downloads/db.sql' at line 1
mysql> mysqldump -h 10.0.0.31 -p -u asfuser asfd8crm > var/downloads

Comment: @MdMaidulIslam looks like you have the flags -p and -u but you need the credentials after each of the flags I believe, rather than both flags and then both credentials, you will also need to specify the db name last. Lastly if thats a real password you might want to delete the comment :-)

Comment: @Opentuned Could you please give me an example query. I did  mysqldump -u [username] -p [password] [dbname] > filename.sql   and mysqldump -h [host] -p -u [user] [database name] > filename.sql   but same error.

Answer (score 25):

Go to command prompt at this path,

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin>`

Then give this command to export your database (**no space after -p**)

`mysqldump -u[username] -p[userpassword] yourdatabase > [filepath]wantedsqlfile.sql`

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump -h 10.0.0.31 -p -u asfuser asfd8crm > var/downloads/db.sql' at line 1
mysql> mysqldump -h 10.0.0.31 -p -u asfuser asfd8crm > var/downloads

Answer (score 20):

To export PROCEDUREs, FUNCTIONs & TRIGGERs too, add `--routines` parameter:

`mysqldump -u YourUser -p YourDatabaseName --routines > wantedsqlfile.sql`

Comment: The switch `--routines` makes the difference :) Any hints how to export only PROCEDUREs, FUNCTIONs & TRIGGERs? For those who have forgotten about the switch and exported "pure" DB without the "algorithms" :)

Comment: BTW the switch `--events` is needed to dump Event Scheduler events, and the TRIGGERs are always exported unless `--skip-triggers` is specified (according to [7.4.5.3 Dumping Stored Programs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump-stored-programs.html))

Comment: @AntonK it is a bit late, but to export only triggers and procedures you can use: mysqldump -u YourUser -p YourDatabaseName -n -d -t --routines --triggers --add-drop-trigger --quote-names --allow-keywords > wantedsqlfile.sql
See https://programalitics.substack.com/p/mysql-database-export-tips for details

Answer (score 16):

The problem with all these solutions (using the `>` redirector character) is that you write your dump from stdout which may break the encoding of some characters of your database.

If you have a character encoding issue. Such as :

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ...

then, you *MUST* use `-r` option to write the file.

MySQL

```sh
mysqldump -u user -pyour-password-without-space-between-letter-p-and-your-password --default-character-set=utf8 --host $HOST database-name -r dump.sql
```

Using Docker

```sh
docker exec --rm -v $pwd:dump -it mysql:5:7 mysqldump -u user -pyour-password-without-space-between-letter-p-and-your-password --default-character-set=utf8 --host $HOST database-name -r dump/dump.sql
```

Note: this mounts the current path as dump inside the instance.

We found the answer [here](https://makandracards.com/makandra/595-dumping-and-importing-from-to-mysql-in-an-utf-8-safe-way)

Conversely, don't use `<` to import your dump into your database, again, your non-utf8 characters may not be passed; but prefer source option.

```sh
mysql -u user -pYourPasswordYouNowKnowHow --default-character-set=utf8 your-database
mysql> SET names 'utf8'
mysql> SOURCE dump.sql
```

Comment: Take care about writing password in the command. It will be saved in the bash history and can break security.

Answer (score 10):

Give this command to export your database, this will include date as well

```
mysqldump -u[username] -p[userpassword] --databases yourdatabase | gzip > /home/pi/database_backup/database_`date '+%m-%d-%Y'`.sql.gz
```

(no space after -p)

Comment: Note, that specifying `--databases` will insert statements as `CREATE DATABASE XYZ;` and `USE XYZ;`, which isn't handy when importing the SQL into another DB with another name...

Answer (score 8):

I have installed my wamp server in D: drive so u have to go to the following path from ur command line->(and if u have installed ur wamp in c: drive then just replace the d: wtih c: here)

```
D:\>cd wamp
D:\wamp>cd bin
D:\wamp\bin>cd mysql
D:\wamp\bin\mysql>cd mysql5.5.8 (whatever ur verserion will be displayed here use keyboard Tab button and select the currently working mysql version on your server if you have more than one mysql versions)
D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8>cd bin
D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\bin>mysqldump -u root -p password db_name > "d:\backupfile.sql"
```

here **root** is user of my phpmyadmin
**password** is the password for phpmyadmin so **if u haven't set any password for root just nothing type at that place,**
db_name is the database (for which database u r taking the backup)
,backupfile.sql is the file in which u want ur backup of ur database and u can also change the backup file location(d:\backupfile.sql) from to any other place on your computer

Comment: Of all the ways I found to do this, this answer is the only one that worked for me. I'm using MySQL version 5.6, so the path was ...\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin for the command prompt. You will have to use your MySQL admin user name and password, those specified for a particular database won't work. Thank you Sachin. Even the instructions in the MySQL manual for v.5.6 don't work. The syntax is incomplete there.

Comment: Does it really work with the space between `-p` and `password`?

Answer (score 8):

```
mysqldump -h [host] -p -u [user] [database name] > filename.sql
```

Example in localhost

```
mysqldump -h localhost -p -u root cookbook > cookbook.sql
```

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump -h 10.0.0.31 -p -u asfuser asfd8crm > var/downloads/db.sql' at line 1
mysql> mysqldump -h 10.0.0.31 -p -u asfuser asfd8crm > var/downloads

Answer (score 5):

```
mysqldump --no-tablespaces -u username -p pass database_name > db_backup_file.sql
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 5):

For import:

```
mysql -u db_username -p newFileName < databasName.sql
```

For export:

```
mysqldump -u db_username -p databasName > newFileName.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

## Syntax

```
(mysqldump.exe full path) -u (user name) -p (password) (database name) > (export database file full path)
```

## Example

```
c:>d:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin\mysqldump.exe -u root -p mydbname > d:\mydb.sql
```

where **d:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin\mysqldump.exe** will be your actual mysqldump.exe path, **mydbname** is the name of database which you want to export and **d:\mydb.sql** is the path where you want to store the exported database.

Answer (score 0):

I have used wamp server. I tried on

```
c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\bin\mysqldump -uroot -p db_name > c:\somefolder\filename.sql
```

`root` is my username for mysql, and if you have any password specify it with:

```
-p[yourpassword]
```

Hope it works.

Comment: --password need to be used if you are tring to type the password as well

Answer (score 0):

**For windows OS** :

When you get error **1064 mysql (42000)** while trying to execute **mysqldump** command, exit from current terminal. And execute mysqldump command.

```
mysql>exit 
c:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysqldump -uroot -p --databases [database_name] > name_for_export_db.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to take the dump of the db which was running on the docker and came up with the below command to achieve the same:

docker exec `<container_id/name>` /usr/bin/mysqldump -u `<db_username>` --password=`<db_password>` `db_name` > .sql

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Login** in your databse server and then **hit** the below command:-

> mysql -u username -p databasename > exportfilename.sql

Then it will ask for password **Enter** the **password** and hit enter,it will take some time your database will be exported.

Answer (score -1):

mysql -u  -p databaseName>fileToPutDatabase

Comment: should be mysqldump

Answer (score -2):

You can use this **script to export or import** any database from terminal
given at this link: https://github.com/Ridhwanluthra/mysql_import_export_script/blob/master/mysql_import_export_script.sh

```
echo -e "Welcome to the import/export database utility\n"
echo -e "the default location of mysqldump file is: /opt/lampp/bin/mysqldump\n"
echo -e "the default location of mysql file is: /opt/lampp/bin/mysql\n"
read -p 'Would like you like to change the default location [y/n]: ' location_change
read -p "Please enter your username: " u_name
read -p 'Would you like to import or export a database: [import/export]: ' action
echo

mysqldump_location=/opt/lampp/bin/mysqldump
mysql_location=/opt/lampp/bin/mysql

if [ "$action" == "export" ]; then
    if [ "$location_change" == "y" ]; then
        read -p 'Give the location of mysqldump that you want to use: ' mysqldump_location
        echo
    else
        echo -e "Using default location of mysqldump\n"
    fi
    read -p 'Give the name of database in which you would like to export: ' db_name
    read -p 'Give the complete path of the .sql file in which you would like to export the database: ' sql_file
    $mysqldump_location -u $u_name -p $db_name > $sql_file
elif [ "$action" == "import" ]; then
    if [ "$location_change" == "y" ]; then
        read -p 'Give the location of mysql that you want to use: ' mysql_location
        echo
    else
        echo -e "Using default location of mysql\n"
    fi
    read -p 'Give the complete path of the .sql file you would like to import: ' sql_file
    read -p 'Give the name of database in which to import this file: ' db_name
    $mysql_location -u $u_name -p $db_name < $sql_file
else
    echo "please select a valid command"
fi
```