# Convert localhost database to server database

Tags: mysql

This may be stupid but am using MySQL on a localhost using XAMPP and I've finished my app and bought a server so how can I upload my localhost database to the server?

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031412/how-to-export-a-mysql-database-using-command-prompt

Answer (score 0):

What your looking for is the "mysqldump" command. simply type 'man mysqldump' which will give you the various options available.

This command will basically produce a text file and with the proper flags include within that file both the complete sequence of commands to recreate your database tables and load the data.

If I recall correctly there are at least two different methods of restoring the data on the other end with the commands being "source" and "load from file" if I'm recalling things right.

Either way the details I've provided should be enough to get you through it with at worst having to drop one or two of the words into Google for a syntax reference.