# WAMPServer phpMyadmin Maximum execution time of 360 seconds exceeded

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, wampserver

I just installed WampServer. It works when I visit my project page but when I try to navigate phpMyAdmin i get this error:

> Maximum execution time of 360 seconds exceeded

What is the problem?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

A better solution here is to change the config that controls phpMyAdmin and not the `php.ini` file.

If you change the `php.ini` file you effect everything in PHP and should you write that infinite loop that we all do from time to time it will take longer to terminate your infinite loop than is sensible.

**Note:** If you are using the 64bit WAMPServer the base folder name will be `wamp64` instead of `wamp` so please amend the below folder names accordingly.

So change `\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf`. By default it will look something like this although your version of phpMyAdmin will probably be different:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/"

<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
  <IfDefine APACHE24>
    Require local
  </IfDefine>
  <IfDefine !APACHE24>
    Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
    </IfDefine>
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

To extend the maximum time limit for importing a database, change the `php_admin_value max_execution_time` parameter. You may also need to change the other parameters as larger databases tend to come in larger files and take longer to read as well. Example:

```
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 1024M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 1024M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 1800
  php_admin_value max_input_time 1800
```

Don't forget to **restart Apache** after making changes to this file.

Comment: Don't forget to reset your WAMP server after changing it if you're like me. Took me good 5 minutes of cursing at the stupid answer on SO that doesn't work before I realized I was the stupid one.

Comment: that file simply doesn't exists on my machine (MySQL 5.5 on Win64).

Comment: @PowerEngineering Hi, are you using WAMPServer or some other mecanism of installing a WAMP Stack?

Comment: @RiggsFolly. No WAMP, just MySQL 5.5 64bit installed on plain Windows Server2012 R2 64bit Datacenter Edition.
The same for the Web Server (DB is on a different machine) but with Apache and PHP 5.5.12.
I solved the problem placing into phpmyadmin config.inc.php the following:
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = secondsToTimeout;

Comment: @PowerEngineering Hi, thanks for the info,  but in that case your config is not WAMPServer and therefore your solution is bound to be different.

Answer (score 11):

In your php/php.ini change `max_execution_time = 360` to `99999`.

**OR**

You can add `ini_set('max_execution_time', 600); //600 seconds = 10 minutes` line on top of your php file.

See, if that works.

Comment: Why is it getting slow?? navigating to a different page should not take too much time

Answer (score 1):

What helped me is to edit `config.inc.php` in `phpmyadmin` folder and changed:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
```

to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

Basically change "localhost" to "127.0.0.1", xampp and wampp differently resolve those two.