# How to Fix Script Timeout Error in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am getting script timeout issue while importing a database from a zip. The error shows as-

> Script timeout passed, if you want to finish import, please resubmit
>   same file and import will resume.

I tried setting `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;` inside *phpmyadmin4.1.14/libraries/config.default.php*.
Also inside my **php.ini** I set both `max_input_time` and `max_execution_time` to 0.

The zip size is around 33 MB and I'm using WAMP server.
What could be the other cases for which I'm getting this error?

Comment: Have you made sure to restart the apache service on wamp?

Comment: yes, several times. Been stuck with this issue from yesterday!

Comment: Try setting it in `phpmyadmin4.1.14/libraries/config.inc.php` instead of the .default.php one.

Comment: Tried that too with no luck! :(

Comment: Make a phpinfo file and check which files are loaded to be sure.
Check to make sure the max_execution time etc are actually 0 on that page.

Comment: please refer to this answer it helped me https://stackoverflow.com/a/29938630/15625279

Answer (score 4):

Since you get script time out, shouldn't you **increase** the `max_execution_time` in `php.ini` instead of reducing it?

Try with the following values:

```
post_max_size = 500M
upload_max_filesize = 500M
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 540
memory_limit = 1000M
```

EDIT: just noticed that `max_execution_time` is hardcoded to `0`, still you can try the above settings.

Comment: I tried these settings, but still having the same error.

Comment: Did you restart your server after the changes to php.ini ?

Comment: Yes, restarted few times, even tried increasing max_execution_time to 6000.

Comment: Something else i found out is that Apache uses a file called `\wamp\bin\php\php{version}\phpForApache.ini` to get its `php.ini` file setting from.
This is the file that should be edited.

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware that apache also has an execution time.

```
Apache Wait Time for Input/Output
Edit file C:\WampDeveloper\Config\Apache\extra\httpd-default.conf
Timeout = 300
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue commonly arise when we working on heavy load php application. This error comes when you are getting bulk of data from database. Then this type of issue come. You should check the following things in you code.

- Check you database queries properly.
- With `Select` statement you should use the `Limit` offset.
- Check each table should have the primary key.

This issue also come when we are upload images or some thing like wise. Some time we did get solution for the heavy load  image's then we try to change the logic and try to solve the issue. One more thing that you should  check you php.ini configuration setting Increase these values in MB.As follows.

```
post_max_size = 500M
upload_max_filesize = 500M
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 540
memory_limit = 1000M
```