# Uploading database works on Xampp but not Wamp? MySql error #1064

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, wampserver

Xampp has been running extremely slow on my machine and I've decided to switch to Wamp. Everything seem to work great except when I'm uploading my WordPress DB to my Wamp installation of phpMyAdmin, but if I upload the same file to Xampp it uploads without any problem.

I keep getting a #1064 error on Wamp.

Any ideas or suggestions as to why?

Comment: `Error #1064` is the most general error you can get. Please provide the full error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wamp phpMyadmin Maximum execution time of 360 seconds exceeded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916516/wamp-phpmyadmin-maximum-execution-time-of-360-seconds-exceeded)

Comment: What version of WAMPServer are you running, some recent versions of phpMyAdmin had some bugs in. If you are using WAMPServer 3 you can upgrade phpMyAdmin to the latest version from the SourceForge repo or the [backup repo here](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) phpMyAdmin 4.6.4 is the latest ADDON available

Comment: I'll give this a try. I ended up going with Binami's Wordpress Stack. It's blazing fast so far!