# phpmyadmin not opening due to change in config file

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

I was trying to upload a large .sql file which have more than 14000 rows. which caused the error `maximum execution time when importing .SQL data file` . Then I searched on google to resolve the issue and followed answers on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817670/php-maximum-execution-time-when-importing-sql-data-file) . So i made some changes in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\config.default.php file by changing `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;` .
Now the issue is that phpmyadmin is not opening on localhost. How can I resolved this issue?

Comment: Have you tried reverting your changes?

Comment: @brombeer Yes i reverted `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 300`. But still not working

Comment: Turn on error reporting ([How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display?rq=1)) to see any errors. Take a look at the server/error logs. Worst case: reinstall xampp

Comment: @brombeer i have turned on error reporting and placed `ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);` on the top of the 'config.default.php' file. But its not displaying any error. Its showing just a blank page

Comment: Any hint in the webserver error log?

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to open phpMyAdmin; are you getting a blank page, an error message, a looping log on, etc?

Comment: @IsaacBennetch showing just a blank page

Comment: Blank pages are usually caused by something that is logged in the webserver error log. What information does that contain?

Answer (score 0):

- Remove `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit']`
- Then Restart `XAMPP` then Try This

  Better way to import large DB :

  - copy the file in `mysql` -> `bin` folder
  - run command within folder and try `command` below :

  ```
  mysql -u root -p -v databasename < dbfiletoimport.sql
  ```

Comment: I have restarted  xampp several times even i restarted my computer several times. But still have the issue.

Comment: Remove $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] Then Restart XAMPP

Comment: I have commented that line. But still have the issue

Answer (score 0):

this problem caught me out too...I was able to start phpmyadmin after opening config.default.php in wordpad and saving it again, seems using notepad stops it from working...I hope this saves someone hours of frustration!

Comment: What `wordpad`??  I think you should never open (at least no save) a PHP file with [WordPad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPad)

Answer (score 0):

Copy files in your Xampp/mysql/data into some where as a backup.
Revert your changes, close Xampp, and copy files in the Xampp/mysql/backup into Xampp/mysql/data. DO NOT Copy and replace ibdata1 and ibtmp1!
Restart xampp server.