# Lost database for phpMyAdmin?

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin

I extracted the phpMyAdmin folder on my desktop to save my database, and I thought I would keep all my threads and posts for [MyBB][1]. Is there any way to retrieve/make the folder into a `.sql` file, or did I just lose about a years worth of threads and posts?

EDIT
Ok so since I have lost no data, how would I properly export it? I have seen that thread you have linked, no luck. Since I have only the folders, and I have switched over to new server host and a new site, how would I be able to access my database? How could I properly reinstall Phpmyadmin and MySQL with all my old data?
Thanks guys for all your help!

Comment: If you didn't delete the DB/tables then all the information is still there, you just have to reinstall phpmyadmin so you can access it.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the only thing you did is remove `phpMyAdmin`, then your data is fine. As commenters have said, all of that lives in your database, for which `phpMyAdmin` is only a (relatively) user-friendly GUI.

If you want to backup your database properly, you need to export it. If you can get `phpMyAdmin` reinstalled, [this article](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/smb-technologist/import-and-export-databases-using-phpmyadmin/) will help you with that. If you can't reinstall `phpMyAdmin`, you can use the MySQL command line interface, which [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3031412/3457753) will help with.