# How to create multiple MySQL tables via PHP using a single query?

Tags: php, mysql, subquery, setup-deployment, create-table

I am trying to create a "setup script" for my website. I would like to create the database, adding tables and some content at the same time. So far this is how I did it, but it seems kind off messy using multiple queries:

```
<?php


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Create database
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE MYDB";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

    echo "1. Database created successfully <br/>";
    $conn->select_db("MYDB");


    $sql_members = "CREATE TABLE MEMBERS (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    USERNAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    EMAIL VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    DISCOUNT VARCHAR(5),
    PASSW CHAR(128),
    ROLE VARCHAR(9)
    )";


    if ($conn->query($sql_members) === TRUE) {
        echo "2. Table MEMBERS created successfully <br/>";
    } else {
        echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
    }

    $sql_content = "CREATE TABLE CONTENT (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    TITLE VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    TEXT VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
    )";

    if ($conn->query($sql_content) === TRUE) {
        echo "3. Table CONTENT created successfully <br/>";
    } else {
        echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
    }



} else {
    echo "Error creating database: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();


?>
```

Is there a better way?
Thanks!

== UPDATE ==

I have tried to export the database and use the resulted .sql file as my setup query, but something is wrong, I get:

> Error creating tables: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO `CONTACTS` (`ID`, `NAME`, `PHONE`,
>   `EMAIL`, `ADDRESS`, `CITY`, `COUN' at line 12

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CONTACTS` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NAME` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_romanian_ci NOT NULL,
  `PHONE` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_romanian_ci NOT NULL,
  `EMAIL` varchar(35) COLLATE utf8_romanian_ci NOT NULL,
  `ADDRESS` text COLLATE utf8_romanian_ci NOT NULL,
  `CITY` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_romanian_ci NOT NULL,
  `COUNTRY` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_romanian_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_romanian_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

INSERT INTO `CONTACTS` (`ID`, `NAME`, `PHONE`, `EMAIL`, `ADDRESS`, `CITY`, `COUNTRY`) VALUES
(1, 'Peter Brown', '0742062307', 'office@shop.com', 'Avenue 13.', 'Santaclaus', 'Austria');
```

== SOLUTUION ==

I needed "multi_query()" for executing my multiple queries.

Comment: you can write all your sql queries in a single file and separate them using `;`

Comment: Read the manual : http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php OR search over stackoverflow : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd ;)

Comment: @BenseidSeid could you plz drop a sample - just in case I miss something. Thanks!

Comment: Do try and relax your column lengths here. Unless you have a very compelling reason use `VARCHAR(255)` by default, *especially* for things like names, cities, and most importantly email addresses.

Comment: It's worth noting that what you're describing here is a very primitive form of *database migration* tool, something most ORMs offer as a core feature. [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/migrations.html), [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations) and [Propel](http://propelorm.org/documentation/09-migrations.html) have this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this too :p

```
$errors = [];

$table1 = "CREATE TABLE MEMBERS (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    USERNAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    EMAIL VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    DISCOUNT VARCHAR(5),
    PASSW CHAR(128),
    ROLE VARCHAR(9)
    )";

$table2 = "CREATE TABLE CONTENT (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    TITLE VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    TEXT VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
    )";


$tables = [$table1, $table2];


foreach($tables as $k => $sql){
    $query = @$conn->query($sql);

    if(!$query)
       $errors[] = "Table $k : Creation failed ($conn->error)";
    else
       $errors[] = "Table $k : Creation done";
}


foreach($errors as $msg) {
   echo "$msg <br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could [export the whole database including all tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031412/how-to-export-a-mysql-database-using-command-prompt) using the command line or using [PhPMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/). Then query the content of the file in php to create the database.

Comment: MAN! This is a freaking good idea!!! I was about to handwrite all the stuff from the beginning. Thanks!!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score -2):

you can create a file and put all your sql queries in it..

```
CREATE TABLE MEMBERS (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    USERNAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    EMAIL VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    DISCOUNT VARCHAR(5),
    PASSW CHAR(128),
    ROLE VARCHAR(9)
);

CREATE TABLE CONTENT (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    TITLE VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    TEXT VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);
```

then in your php code:

```
$query = file_get_contents ('queries.sql');

if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
    echo "all tables created successfully <br/>";
} else {
    echo "Error creating tables: " . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: I have exported, and tried to use the .sql for my setup script, but I get an error when it comes to insert data into the tables, could you check out my updated answer plz?

Comment: Is `=== TRUE` here really necessary?