# Unable to export entire db

Tags: mysql

I'm unable to export my database.
I have tried several times unsuccessfully including:

```
mysqldump -u root -p --opt --db_2 -r backup.sql;
```

and

```
mysqldump --database --user=root --password db_2 > export_into_db.sql;
```

I get this error with both of them:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'mysqldump --database --user=root --password db_2 >
>   export_into_db.sql' at line 1

Comment: Are you running this from the command line?

Comment: Yes I am running it from the command line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to export a mysql database using Command Prompt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031412/how-to-export-a-mysql-database-using-command-prompt)

Comment: @Arslan.H It looks very much like you're trying to run this as an SQL query.

Comment: Sorry, I meant are you running this from a command line prompt or from within the mysql environment?

Comment: I run this form terminal I'm on mac

Comment: What does the prompt (the text in the terminal to the left of what you enter) say?

Comment: Or what do you get when you run `echo $SHELL`?

Comment: i asnwered it :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anyone who is using mac you need to do the following steps in order to export the sql:

```
1.open a new terminal window
2.type this to enter the mysql if your unable to enter it PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
3.mysqldump -u root -p db_2 >/Users/your_name/Desktop/sql.sql;
4.type password
```