# MySQL 5.7 - Export Dump

Tags: mysql

I have tried several syntax:

```
mysqldump -uroot -p<passwd> world_innodb > D:/labs/world_innodb_backup.sql
mysqldump -u root -p <passwd> world_innodb > D:/labs/world_innodb_backup.sql
mysqldump world_innodb > D:/labs/world_innodb_backup.sql
mysqldump --user=root --databases=world_innodb > D:/labs/world_innodb_backup.sql
```

I have also tried with back slash instead of slash.

In all cases it shows a new line with prompt "->". Writing ";" returns always syntax error without any clue about what part of the syntax has the error.

Any idea?

Comment: Possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031412/how-to-export-a-mysql-database-using-command-prompt ?

Comment: Try to execute `mysqldump` from the Command Line of the operating system (for example, PowerShell), not from the MySQL Command Line.

Comment: I seemed to work on command line (not in Shell), but the command did not showed any text message about its execution (successfull or failed). How can I get a logfile of the operation?