# Mysql database backup from Linux machine

Tags: mysql

Can any one suggest me the efficient way to take backup of Mysql database automatically from linux. So Data integrity is maintained.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to export a mysql database using Command Prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031412/how-to-export-a-mysql-database-using-command-prompt)

Comment: If we are taking the backup of production enviroment then there will be any issue with data integrity or downtime.

Comment: For production environment, I can recommend you taking a look at [Database replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html)

Comment: thanks for the solution

Comment: Can we use the mysqldump in production enviroment ?

Comment: Yes but I won't recommend it if your database is becoming large. The save time would be long, generating a significant downtime. Replication is the way to go because on top of having a backup, you also have an automatic fallback if the server for the main database falls.