# Update XAMPP to PHP 8.1, Keep MySQL Databases

Tags: php, windows, xampp

I have XAMPP with PHP 7.x on **Windows** 10.

When I install new XAMPP that supports PHP 8.1, there is no option to upgrade the older.
And setup don't accept current XAMPP folder.
I can backup htdocs folder and uninstall my older XAMPP.

How I a keep my MySQL databases? (or backup, if there id no way to keep them)

Comment: Please use `phpmyadmin` to export all your Mysql data into a sqldump file.

Comment: simple export the database https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031412/how-to-export-a-mysql-database-using-command-prompt and then simply update XAMPP !!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to export a mysql database using Command Prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031412/how-to-export-a-mysql-database-using-command-prompt)

Comment: No, I want to **keep** databases, or if there is no way, backup all of my databases in XAMMP on Windows. Unfortunately `mysqldump` not worked here.

Comment: Search/Find mysqldump.exe. This file location maybe in **C:\Program Files\MariaDB x.y\bin\mysqldump.exe** Then add **C:\Program Files\MariaDB x.y\bin** path to your windows environment `PATH`. close any command prompt window and re-open it. Now your `mysqldump` should work.

Comment: Solved by manually backup/restore. But why XAMPP installer has no **option to upgrade** older installed version?! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found `mysqldump` in `c:\xampp\mysql\bin` folder.

I used `--all-databases` parameter to dump all my dbs:

```
mysqldump -u USER_NAME -p PASSWORD --all-databases > BACKUP_PATH.sql
```

Tanks All.